# Need help with a proper Sunyaev-Zeldovich-effect tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, specific-tag

When posting [Why does the first measurements of the thermal Sunyaev-Zel’dovich effect from ALMA show a temperature decrease and not an increase at the cluster?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48356/7982) I tried to add a Sunyaev-Zeldovich-effect tag. I copied "Sunyaev–Zeldovich effect" from Wikipedia and added a second hyphen, but the first dash was not recognized by the tag generating algorithm as a candidate for a hyphen, so now we have a `sunyaevzeldovich-effect` tag rather than a `sunyaev-zeldovich-effect` tag with two hyphens.

Trying to create the doubly-hyphened tag is rejected as being "too close" to an existing tag.

I think in this case I need some help from moderators to delete the existing tag?

Then I plan to create a good tag and add it to:

- [Non-thermal Sunyaev-Zel'dovich effect](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30289/7982)
- [Why does the first measurements of the thermal Sunyaev-Zel’dovich effect from ALMA show a temperature decrease and not an increase at the cluster?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48356/7982)
- [Explain as simply as possible how the Sunyaev-Zeldovich (SZ) effect is used to estimate the Hubble constant](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44469/7982)

and perhaps

- [How is it determined that the X-ray and radio intensity come from a magnetic field bridge between two clusters of galaxies?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32199/7982)
- [Is the universe macroscopically transparent to CMB? Is the fraction intercepted by stars and dust so tiny that it doesn't have a correction factor?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43458/7982)

Comment: Alright, I fixed the tag. Feel free to tag other questions.